# Find the points on a curve where the slope/direction changes

Tags: r, histogram

Here is a sample data

```
data<-rbeta(7974, 1, 8, ncp = 0)
hist(data)
```

The data lies between 0 and 1 (basically a proportion data) and is also skewed. The histogram looks like this:

[image]

This data actually shows the proportion of area covered by crops for different locations. Here is a curve of this histogram using this:

```
d1 <- density(data)
plot(d1$x, d1$y, type = "n")
lines(d1, col = "blue")
```

[image]

How can I get a list of the x-values of the inflection points (Where the curve of the blue line changes its slope from positive to negative)? It probably be could done using calculus but I am not from a maths background and was wondering if there is any R package that could do it.

The proportion value shows how much area is covered under crop for a location. I have 7974 locations and this graph shows for each location how much area is covered under crop. I want to convert this proportion to binary data i.e. yes or no (1 and 0) whether the location has crop or not. In a way I am converting a continuous data into binary data. The way I thought I will do this is by selecting a threshold value above which everything is 1 (crop present) and the rest is 0 (absent). That is why I am looking for a threshold value which I think my inflection point can tell me.

Comment: As far as data, you can [simulate from a beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with `rbeta`. For your problem, it sounds like you want to chase down the little irregularities that are probably artifacts of the chosen smoothing kernel, which sounds pointless. There's not an R package to do that. Perhaps you could tell us what the end goal is?

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited the question slightly to make it more clear why I want to do this.

Comment: Where the slope changes from positive to negative is a local maximum, not an inflection point. It is also an artifact of the kernel density smoothing method. Why not just take a quantile - the 0.25 or 0.5 (median) quantile is probably a better way to get such information. Or if you really want a mode, bin your data (use `cut` and a small binwidth, or even just use `hist` with `breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)`) and take the center of the most common bin.

Comment: And it's not much more clear. If you really want help, tell us the goal. Presumably you're doing *something* more than picking a point at which to round up or down. The **reason** you are doing this can probably inform an appropriate method.

Comment: Some more edits. This time I have tried to make it clear and the actual reason why I want to do this. thanks

Comment: The more you tell me, the more I think the methods in my second comment (use a quantile or use binning) make more sense than the method you propose. If you *really* want the question re-opened, the biggest thing you could do to improve it would be to make it reproducible by sharing some data.

Comment: Personally, I would be more comfortable with an arbitrary (50%, 75%, 90%) cutoff to determining what defines as cropland, any choice is going to be arbitrary, and it might as well be explicit, rather than using statistics to make it seem objective. That way it could be tailored to the question, or use a generally accepted level used in the field of study. That being said, finding the inflection point of a curve like this one in r _would_ be a very interesting programming question. The question is well defined now, maybe it could be taken off hold to see if someone has an answer?

Comment: Thanks. I have made more changes. Have given a sample data to work with. Hope now this the hold will be taken off

Comment: You get the `x`-value of the local maxima with `d1$x[which.max(d1$y)]`. But as already mentioned by @Gregor it is hard to distinguish between "black and white" in your data. See also here `hist(data);par(new = T);plot(sort(data), 1:length(data),axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA);axis(4)`.